# Is it possible to use pango markup text on a Gtk+ 3 toolbutton label using Glade and PyDev?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, glade, pango

I have put together a Gtk+ interface in Glade and part of the UI is a tool palette with several toolbuttons using utf-8 characters as labels.  They work fine in the default font, but I would like to change font details using pango markup.  This is straightforward when dealing with a label as such, as one can apply

```
label.set_markup(pangoMarkupString)
```

but the label in a toolbutton can not, as far as I can tell, be addressed directly in this way.  A naive

```
button.label.set_markup(pangoMarkupString)
```

naturally doesn't work and returns an error saying that *toolbuttons* do not have the *label* property.  Is there any way to use pango parsed text in a toolbutton, and what depth of python trickery would be required at the application end?

Comment: Does [toolbutton.get_label_widget()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkToolButton.html#gtk-tool-button-get-label-widget) help?

Comment: You've certainly identified where I'd gone wrong.  I'd chosen a mere text label, rather than a widget.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To save any others from hours of fruitless head-scratching and searching, and to open the eyes of other newbies to the powers of Gtk+ 3 and Glade, I present the solution I found.

1. Right click on your tool palette in the *outliner* and select edit
2. Choose the hierarchy tab in the editor
3. Select your button in the hierarchy *outliner*
4. Under **Label** properties choose *widget* rather than *text*
5. Click on the selector icon at the right of the widget entry box
6. Add a new widget
7. Leave the tool palette editor
8. Select *label1*, the new widget you created in the *outliner*
9. You can now edit its id, label text and attributes

I don't need it yet, but I wonder how to do this with a regular button...